# Parse.Cloud.run() not fulfilling promise

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, backend

I am using Parse's Cloud code, using `Parse.Cloud.run()` to execute a Cloud function. In the documentation it says it

> Returns a promise that is resolved with the result of the operation

However, this Promise is never being resolved (neither fulfilled nor rejected).

```
Parse.Cloud.run("someCloudFunction", {
    userId: user.id
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Even with this simple example, the console is silent. The function itself is being called correctly, and returning the appropriate response. This can be confirmed in the logs.

Is this a known issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you uploaded your code on the cloud.
your parse application should have this method "someCloudFunction" on the cloud in order to return something.

Upload this code on cloud using parse.exe. You can find instruction here [parseCloud](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code)

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
 response.success("Hello world!");
 });
```

Now to call it as

```
Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
success: function(result) {
// result is 'Hello world!'
 },
error: function(error) {
}
});
```

Comment: The function was correctly defined, however there was a pitfall one of my team members did not cover that was not calling either success or error callbacks, and the input provided was matching this failure. But again, Parse's awesome (hint: not) error logging did not mention that, since it was being called from inside a job. Logic? Nowhere to be found.

Comment: @Kroltan so the issue was only that you didn't call success and error callbacks..? and you were expecting that this should be printed in the console as an error..?

Comment: I was expecting the classic "Success/error not called" which happens when you don't call either from a cloud function.